# Can not import stackless after stackless python installation

Tags: python, python-stackless

I used pycharm and eclipse+pydev, and I also installed stackless python(2.7.1) for mac os x.
when I try to import stackless, there always are tips which is "can't find such package/reference", but when I switch to IDLE/Client, "import stackless" is correct. I really don't know the reason, please help me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PyDev, provided you can launch it from a shell and it's just not finding it in the code analysis, you should be able to make it work by adding 'stackless' to the forced builtins: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not in your PYTHONPATH in that environment. Check to ensure the module is in your PYTHONPATH and that it is being set in the environment in which python launches. This is typically accomplished by adding the appropriate entry to your .bashrc or environment.plist.